# FineUploader - params dont get added to deleteFile

Tags: fine-uploader

I am using the param option in the deleteFile settings to send a temporary ID that I use throughout the page

```
    deleteFile: {
    enabled: true,
    forceConfirm: false,
    method: 'POST',
    endpoint: 'myendpoint',
    params: {tempID: 'MYFIXEDID'}

},
```

No post value for tempID is passed in the request. The same syntax works ok for the request settings.

Comment: This may very well be a bug in Fine Uploader. [As the support page explains](http://fineuploader.com/support.html), bugs should be filed in the GitHub project's issue tracker. Please delete this question and file an issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is confirmed as a bug in version 5.3.2. Request has been opened on the issue tracker.

I have left this question and answer here in case others are having the same issue.

Comment: I'm not sure this is specific to 5.3.2. How have you verified?

Comment: I havent, I'm just stating that it is definitely in 5.3.2 =)

Comment: After further investigation, I have determined that there is _not_ a bug in Fine Uploader. Please see [the associated GitHub case](https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader/issues/1488) for details.